# Hot Deploy to multiple tomcat servers

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, cargo

I want to deploy a WAR to multiples tomcat servers (they may change) and do this from a java project.

I've searched and i find cargo, but in cargo i need to know all the servers were i want to deploy my WAR and create a config file with them. The thing is that those servers will change for sure in my enviroment (i may add some, remove some or modify some).

Is there any way i can do what i want?
i'll repeat what i want: From an java app deploy a WAR to a list of tomcat servers (running servers)

PS: sry for my english

EDIT:
this is an example of what i want to do:

Every tomcat its independent from the rest, its like ATM's and i want to "update" their "software" every time in a while, an ATM may be removed or added. so the number of ATM's to update may change

Comment: Are your Tomcat servers installed in a single directory?  You could use Java's `File` objects to create a list.

Comment: all the tomcat servers are in diferents pc, i get the diferents ip from a DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you publish your WAR file into a Maven repository and then use that as a platform for deployment? See the diagram in the following answer:

- [Should Artifactory NOT be used to capture the build artifacts that Jenkins produces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891890/should-artifactory-not-be-used-to-capture-the-build-artifacts-that-jenkins-produ/11893546#11893546)

This approach would neatly decouple the process that builds your software from the process(es) that deploy your software. Specifically you won't have to track your deployments in Maven anymore.

Comment: sry for my ignorance but doing it this way, will i be able to "update" the war every time i want to?

Comment: @LautaroMena Absolutely. You can publish a new release of the WAR file into Nexus each time or a timestamped development snapshot. Very very useful for tracking changes between builds, especially during QA testing.

Comment: cargo have a java api that i can use from my project, but i'll try this too and i'll chose w/e fits me better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with maven-deploy-plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ftp.html

You can configure where to put WAR file, there are possibilities to deploy using ssh or ftp protocol.

Comment: i've seen that, but the problem is that u need to define a profile for every server where u want to deploy the WAR

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your Tomcats in a cluster, use the FarmWarDeployer.

Comment: Every tomcat its independent from the rest, its like ATM's and i want to "update" their "software" every time in a while, an ATM may be removed or added. so the number of ATM's to update may change